# Setting axis scales in ChartsJS

Tags: chart.js

I am using ChartsJS for a django project.
What I am trying to do is to set the "Y" axis to start at 0.

My graph should have 3 bars in it. Except the axis currently starts at the lowest value of my data. Hence it looks like one bar is missing.
I have been playing around with the options section of code to try and edit the y axis but i can't figure it out. any suggestions?

```
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Number of faults'
         },
         responsive: false,

         scales: {
              y: {
                suggestedMin: 0
                 }
                }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They have an option for this `beginAtZero`

```
scales: {
   y: {
     beginAtZero: true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, this fixed it:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
  
            min: 0
        }
    }]
},
```